# Convert black and white image to grey

Tags: javascript, css

I need to convert a black and white image to grey shade using javascript. I have already used a greyscale fuunction to convert color image to greyscale. My client uploaded a pure black text image which he needs to convert to a little greyshade.
Is this possible.

Comment: you can use css filter or can try http://camanjs.com/

Comment: Though the above is the best available suggestion, I need to point out that using the above method, all the black in the entire image will be the same shade of gray. If the image already has a halftone or other dithering effect to approximate gray (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) then you could implement a "descreen" filter in JS canvas to make it into grayscale, but that might be prohibitively costly, especially compared to using Photoshop. Otherwise, there's no way to change the image to have different shades of gray without blurring it in some way. Best to request a new photo.